# How do I align my submenu in a CSS drop down box according to the location of menu item

Tags: html, css, alignment, submenu, dropdown

I have a css drop down menu with 2 sub menus. A horizontal bar which has one item that drops down vertically. When you hover over the sub menu, another sub menu pops out to the right...The first item is directly to the right of the hovered item...The problem, is when there are a bunch of items, you have to scroll the page down to see them...I want to vertically center it or show it at the very top of the submenu...

Below is the CSS

```
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;

}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #F21201;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFE973;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;

}


#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #009ae1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  border: solid 1px Black;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 32px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #FFE973;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I've changed `cssmenu ul ul ul top:` to a negative number, but when you select one of the top submenus, it goes up too far and has the opposite problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/zvqz9xdm/

Comment: can you post the html? or a demo at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Please post the HTML

Comment: Done. I've never used jsfiddle before. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

> I've changed `#cssmenu ul ul ul` `top` to a negative number, but when
>   you select one of the top submenus, it goes up too far and has the
>   opposite problem.

I think you were close. The problem is you were applying the adjustment to *all* sub submenus, as opposed to only the ones that were overflowing.

So, right now, all "MENU" items from "Appetizers" to "Sweet & Sour" display their submenus mostly within range. No problems there.

The problem begins with "Chow Mein", where a series of items begin to overflow the parent menu.

In your code, you have all sub submenus positioned to the top of the container:

```
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

For each submenu starting at "Chow Mein" and ending at "Platters, you will need to adjust the `top` property to shift them into the desired range.

I didn't use a single class with a `top` or `bottom` adjustment applied to all overflowing menus because "platters" is way too long and the shorter menus still need to align with their parent menu item, or the hovering will break.

Replace the `<ul>` for each of the following menu items with the adjusted code.

```
<ul class="align1">  <!-- Chow Mein -->
<ul class="align2">  <!-- Curry -->
<ul class="align3">  <!-- Chop Suey -->
<ul class="align4">  <!-- Beef -->
<ul class="align5">  <!-- Poultry -->
<ul class="align6">  <!-- Platters -->
```

Then add these rules to your CSS:

```
#cssmenu ul ul ul.align1  {  top: -100px;  }
#cssmenu ul ul ul.align2  {  top: -40px;   }
#cssmenu ul ul ul.align3  {  top: -125px;  }
#cssmenu ul ul ul.align4  {  top: -30px;   }
#cssmenu ul ul ul.align5  {  top: -30px;   }
#cssmenu ul ul ul.align6  {  top: -350px;  }
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/zvqz9xdm/4/